# jScrollPanel jQuery costom scroll re-render

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

If i install the jScrollPanel it works fine, but when i try to catch content from ajax, it doesn't make the scrollbar, because it still thinks there is no  content in.

So my question is, how can i re-render the jScrollPanel, so it now it has to put scrollbar on/off?

Here is my catching script:

```
 "chatlog": function() {
      $.ajax({url: '?chatlog=&' + new Date(),success: function(data){
         if ( nagoom.trim(data) != "") {
            $('#__chatlog').html(data);

        }
      }});
     }
```

Here is where i install it:

```
$('aside .chat-entity').jScrollPane({
        showArrows: true,
        verticalGutter: -13,
        autoReinitialise: true
});
```

I am using this script http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/less_basic.html

Comment: Can you share your html code?

Comment: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/less_basic.html that script

Comment: Is it a one time load or do you need to periodically retrieve the content

Comment: Yes, i have setInterval("chatLog()", 1250), so everytime it has to check if scroll has to be on/off

Comment: Can you share your code and any errors displayed in firebug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently there is a reinitialise method on the API object. Include this in your response function. More information on this can be found [here](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html)

EDIT: I have not used this script before so I hesitate to provide code, but I assume it would work something like this:

```
success: function(data){
     if ( nagoom.trim(data) != "") {
        $('#__chatlog').html(data);
        jScrollPaneObjectReference.data('jsp').reinitialise();
    }
  }
```

where jScrollPaneObjectReference is the object returned when you constructed the panel

EDIT: I will clarify further. jScrollPaneObjectReference should refer to the object returned when you do this:

```
$('aside .chat-entity').jScrollPane({ showArrows: true, verticalGutter: -13, autoReinitialise: true });
```

Try putting this at the top of your code:

```
window.jScrollPaneObjectReference = $('aside .chat-entity').jScrollPane({ showArrows: true, verticalGutter: -13, autoReinitialise: true });
```

EDIT: Try removing the autoReinitialise parameter.

Comment: I've tried  API.reinitialise(); and API = $('aside .chat-entity').jScrollPane({
   showArrows: true,
   verticalGutter: -13,
   autoReinitialise: true
  });

Comment: It says Uncaught ReferenceError: jScrollPaneObjectReference is not defined

Comment: You are using the wrong object as API. In your comment above, use var ref = $('aside .chat-entity').jScrollPane({ showArrows: true, verticalGutter: -13, autoReinitialise: true }); then ref.data('jsp') is the API object. Call the reinitialise method on that.

Comment: yes, as I mentioned "where jScrollPaneObjectReference is the object returned when you constructed the panel"

Comment: I have tried that.  var o =  $('aside .chat-entity').jScrollPane({
   showArrows: true,
   verticalGutter: -13,
   autoReinitialise: true
  });
  API = o.data("jsp"); and then API.reinitialise() true

Comment: And have debugged. alert(API) does return object Object

Comment: I have tried your code, but still not working. :-/ No errors.

Comment: what happens when you reinitialise?